# How to check a greenplum database table transactions history?

Tags: database, postgresql, greenplum

How to check a greenplum database table transactions history ?

Answer (score 0):

In "gpperfmon" database, in "public" schema, in "queries_history" table. You can query from that table and see all the queries that were ran in GP. From that table you can find the transactions happened on your required table.

Below link describes creation of the gpperfmon Database

https://gpcc.docs.pivotal.io/310/gpcc/topics/setup-collection-agents.html